# how to use antcontrib svn ant. error Cause: The name is undefined

Tags: java, svn, ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to use ant antcontrib , I add the jar file in a folder and I point it using `pathelement`

```
        <pathelement location="D:\pppp\SVN1.8.Client\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
```

but using the below code I ma getting this error

```
build failed
\TEST.xml:59: Problem: failed to create task or type trycatch
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

```
<target name="Add2SvnKw">

    <path id="path.svnant">
        <pathelement location="D:\pppp\SVN1.8.Client\svnant.jar" />
        <pathelement location="D:\pppp\SVN1.8.Client\svnClientAdapter.jar" />
        <pathelement location="D:\pppp\SVN1.8.Client\svnkit-javahl-1.8.0.jar" />
        <pathelement location="D:\pppp\SVN1.8.Client\svnkit-1.8.0.jar" />
        <pathelement location="D:\pppp\SVN1.8.Client\sequence-library-1.0.2.jar" />
        <pathelement location="D:\pppp\SVN1.8.Client\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
        </path>

    <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="path.svnant" />

    <svnSetting svnkit="false" javahl="false" id="svn.settings" 
        username="*******" password="******$" failonerror="false"
        dateFormatter="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    />

     <trycatch property="error-prop" >
          <try>
            <svn refid="svn.settings">

                <singleinfo target="***url" property="revision.result" request="revision" />
            </svn>  
          </try>
          <catch>
            <echo message=" there is an error catched..."/>
          </catch>
        </trycatch>


    <echo message="File Name: ${name.result}" />
    <echo message="Author of last commit: ${author.result}" />
    <echo message="Date of last commit: ${lastDate.result}" />
    <echo message="revision of last commit: ${revision.result}" />

</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added this and it worked

```
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" classpathref="path.svnant" />
```